# Call a function defined in a shell script from a subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I have a Python script (Python 3.6) that is intended to be called from a shell script. This shell script defines some functions prior to calling the Python script. In the Python code, I'd like to use these functions within a subprocess.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do

```
# Shell script
function func1() {
    echo "func1 completed"
}
python /path/to/my_script.py
```

The Python script

```
# my_script.py
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("func1",
                     stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                     shell = True)
```

However, when running that, I get the error: `/bin/sh: func1: command not found`.

I've tried it using `shell = False`, passing `env = os.environ`, and with `os.system` but I get similar errors. Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a separate script for each function and call these decoupled scripts with `Popen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the file with `source` or just `.` then invoke function. Source will load bash script defined functions.
The right way will be `source my_scripts.sh && func1`.

EDIT:
I came with this solution.

```
bash
#!/bin/bash
function func1() {
    echo "func1 completed"
}
function invoke_python(){
    python a.py
}
if [ -z "$@" ]; then
    invoke_python 
else
    "$@"
fi
```

and for python I got that.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("./a.sh func1",
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        shell = True)
p.wait()
```

Comment: There is somewhat of a circle in there. Are you executing your script.sh or your python script first? Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818119/how-can-i-run-a-function-from-a-script-in-command-line)

Comment: I believe that thread you pointed is the best answer for this question :)!

Comment: That seems not to be working because the shell script calls the Python script, so when I source the first from within the second, it looks like they are getting into an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently trying to figure it out :), it's more complicated than I thought.

Comment: Edited :). It's based on solution from thread mentioned by @MarcoMilanesio