# quotation marks in bash script around $@?

Tags: bash

I found the following snippet of bash script from [How can I run a function from a script in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818119/how-can-i-run-a-function-from-a-script-in-command-line)

```
$ cat test.sh
testA() {
  echo "TEST A $1";
}

testB() {
  echo "TEST B $2";
}

"$@"
```

This works well. 
One of the response of this answer is `Use "$@" in most cases. $@ is not safe in some cases`

I'm wondering why `$@` needs quotation marks, `"$@"` , in the last line.
What makes it difference with or without quotation marks around `$@` in the bash script?

Comment: If any of the arguments contain spaces or glob characters then unquoted `$@` will create problems

Comment: The duplicates are ordered intentionally -- the answer to the first of them is most directly on-point.

Answer (score 0):

`"$@"` quotes each positional paremeter that is expanded. For example:

```
# script.sh
cat "$@"
cat $@
```

If you do `script "a b"` the first `cat` will try to emit a file literally named `a b`. Since the positional parameters aren't quoted for the second `cat`, it will try to emit individual files named `a` and `b`. This can cause all kinds of problems since the user quoted the value passed to `script` and expected it to be handled as one word/unit.

Note that `"$@"` is a bit special since if you do `script "a b" "c d"` this expands to: `cat "a b" "c d"` in the script rather than `cat "a b c d"`. The second line would do `cat a b c d` which tries to concatenate four different files rather than two files with spaces in the name.

Comment: It's worth noting that `cat $@` behaves identically to `cat $*` -- it's only with quotes in place that there's any distinction in behavior between the constructs.

Comment: (Also, you might consider an example that can be expanded to include globs to demonstrate that behavior as well as string-splitting -- ie. `./script '* READ ME FIRST *.txt'`, in which case either `$@` or `$*` unquoted will replace the `*` and `*.txt` with lists of files in the current directory).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks; I'll leave your comment as an example of that. I really just wanted to illustrate the difference in general and indicate that it can be dangerous or cause unexpected behavior. That could really be anything including security issues.