# Xcode/Swift: How to add extra argument to a bash execution

Tags: swift, bash, macos, process

I have this Code:

```
func syncShellExec(path: String?) {
    let script             = [path!]
    let process            = Process()
    let outputPipe         = Pipe()
    let filelHandler       = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading

    process.launchPath     = "/bin/bash"
    process.arguments      = script
    process.standardOutput = outputPipe
    .
    .
    .
```

In Swift I call it this way:

```
self.syncShellExec(path: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "initial", ofType: "command"))
```

Now I want to add an Extra argument for the script itself (using Functions within the Bashscript). In Terminal it would be like this:

```
/usr/bin/bash initial.command Do_My_Function
```

How to add this to the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a “variadic parameter” to your Swift function,
and append the arguments to `process.arguments`:

```
func syncShellExec(path: String, args: String...) {

    let process            = Process()
    process.launchPath     = "/bin/bash"
    process.arguments      = [path] + args

    // ...
}
```

Now you can call for example:

```
let scriptPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "initial", ofType: "command")!

syncShellExec(path: scriptPath)
syncShellExec(path: scriptPath, args: "Do_My_Function")
syncShellExec(path: scriptPath, args: "arg1", "arg2")
```

*Remark:* The `syncShellExec()` function expects a path to a script,
therefore I would not make that parameter optional and force-unwrap
it inside the function. On the other hand, `Bundle.main.path(...)`
would only return nil if the resource is missing. That is a 
*programming error* so that force-unwrapping the return value is
justified.

If the number of arguments is only determined at runtime then
you can define the arguments as an array

```
func syncShellExec(path: String, args: [String] = [])
```

and call it as

```
syncShellExec(path: scriptPath)
syncShellExec(path: scriptPath, args: ["Do_My_Function"])
syncShellExec(path: scriptPath, args: ["arg1", "arg2"])
```

Comment: I get this Error at process.arguments: Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?     If a add the ! I get: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String]' and 'String?'

Comment: @Sascha7777: Did you add the `!` at  `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "initial", ofType: "command")!` as I suggested?

Comment: Ok I inserted it your way. Compiles fine but has no Function:
http://fs5.directupload.net/images/180701/zyvuiqh6.png and
http://fs5.directupload.net/images/180701/gfjrmgfe.png

Comment: @Sascha7777: What does the shell script look like?

Comment: @Sascha7777: That script only defines a function. Are you sure that calling `/usr/bin/bash initial.command _ExecuteIt` from the shell would call that function? – Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16159057/1187415.

Comment: I´m so stupid. Calling a function which was not defined before but later couldn´t work. :) Now it works fine. Thank you.