# Is there a way to activate autocomplete for shell scripts funtions?

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

Let's say for example we have a `commands.sh` script like the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

func1() {
 echo "func1"
}

# based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16159057/12894926
"$@"
```

If we type `./commands.sh fu<TAB>` it won't be autocompleted to `./commands.sh func1`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: use `complete -C command ...`

Comment: Nobody would expect that the argument to _command.sh_ would be the name of a bash function. While permitted, the vast majority of program arguments are filenames. Furthermore, at the point of invoking `commands.sh`, nobody can know what functions will exist once the script runs, so even a clever completion function can not figure out how to complete this, unless you implement a specific completion system just for your _command.sh_ (similar like git completion is doing this). You can study [git completion](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash).